# NSMutableArray addObject from sqlite database not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray that I want to populate with an sqlite database and display the data in a table view. The app builds and shows "database opened" in the console but just shows an empty tableview, I had it working perfectly but suddenly it seems to have stopped working. here is the code for adding the data to the array:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize entries;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //[entries addObject:@"object1"];
        //[entries addObject:@"object2"];
        //[entries addObject:@"object3"];
        //[entries addObject:@"object4"];
        [self openDB];
        entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM speakers ORDER BY name"];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
                NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];

                NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", field2Str];
                [entries addObject:str ];


            }
        }
    }
//file path to db
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"speakerdb.sqlite"];
}

//open the db
-(void)openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0,@"error preparing statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
```

The NSMutableArray is defined in the header file as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "speakerViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    IBOutlet UITableView *theTable;
    sqlite3 *db;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *entries;
@end
```

Here is the code for adding the data to the table view:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Return the number of rows in the section
    return [entries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Congigure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

The data shows in the table view if I add objects to the array manually (commented out lines shown in the viewDidLoad method) but doesnt seem to work from the sqlite database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I'm using xcode 5.1.1

Comment: char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);

Comment: thanks but that didn't work, think it needs to be 1 as its the second column i want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your code... Put a break point on `NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];` row, and check that field2 is not empty...

try to open db like this:

```
 NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"speakerdb"
                                                             ofType:@"sqlite"];

        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
```

And one thing is missing from your code:

```
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

use it like this:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
                NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];

                NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", field2Str];
                [entries addObject:str ];


            }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! adding those changes has worked! Think it was the missing sqlite3_finalize(statement); that did the trick